# How to change unicode to parse quotes in Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing, unicode, quotes

I have string in Python like below:

```
strContent = "aaa=\'www.start.com\'bbb"
```

Now I would like to get string www.start.com from strContent. To do this I go through each of the element in the strContent and compare with '\'' and when I founded '\'' I have been adding to new string elements till next '\''.
The output of this was www.start.com\ -> ending with \ -> and I don't want to have \, I just simply want to have www.start.com. I think that I need to change unicode, because compiler doesn't know that this \' in strContent is qoutes.
Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I *think* I sort-of understand the question, but I fail to see what it has got to do with Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously a small part of a big problem, but can't you simply `split` your string?

```
>>> strContent = "aaa=\'www.start.com\'bbb"
>>> strContent.split("\'")
['aaa=', 'www.start.com', 'bbb']
>>> strContent.split("\'")[1]
'www.start.com'
```